# Localhost not displaying any contents

Tags: linux, apache2, localhost, debian, lamp

My localhost does not showing any previous contents it has, after normal system update.
What could be the possible reason for this.
However, I was able to connect to phpmyadmin.
If localhost location changed from /var/www/ to another, what could be the possible location?

System details:

Operating system - debian testing (Jessie) x86_64

```
Index of /
[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
Apache/2.4.7 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80
```

# /usr/sbin/apache2 -V

```
[Tue Mar 11 21:41:55.901363 2014] [core:warn] [pid 19737] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Tue Mar 11 21:41:55.901541 2014] [core:warn] [pid 19737] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Tue Mar 11 21:41:55.901569 2014] [core:warn] [pid 19737] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Tue Mar 11 21:41:55.901583 2014] [core:warn] [pid 19737] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Tue Mar 11 21:41:55.901616 2014] [core:warn] [pid 19737] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Tue Mar 11 21:41:55.932506 2014] [core:warn] [pid 19737] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Tue Mar 11 21:41:55.932942 2014] [core:warn] [pid 19737] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Tue Mar 11 21:41:55.932966 2014] [core:warn] [pid 19737] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

# ps -ef | grep apache

```
root     16811     1  0 20:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16815 16811  0 20:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16816 16811  0 20:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16817 16811  0 20:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16818 16811  0 20:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16819 16811  0 20:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16820 16811  0 20:47 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Comment: i was the same problem, this works for me!

http://askubuntu.com/questions/452042/why-is-my-apache-not-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-14-04

Bye!

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly because your system's root has changed  from `/var/wwww` to `/var/www/html` due to the system update.

To solve this,go to:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

and set

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

You need root permission to edit the file. From terminal

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

and then edit the file and save.

After this restart your server from the terminal.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```